# Audacity & OPUS Files?

Tags: 17.04, audacity, ogg-opus

How can I get Audacity to work with Opus files? Is there a plugin I can get?

I've heard that I can point Audacity to a framework for encoding/decoding and delegate the work to the framework, since Audacity doesn't support `.opus` yet.

How should I go about adding `.opus` support to Audacity?

Edit 0: (After trying the external program and the file not appearing):
[image: Export Audio]
[image: Program Output]

Edit 1: After Recompiling
A file with the file name now appears in the folder, but it appears to be unplayable.
[image: After Recompiling]

Comment: audacity should open an .opus file just fine (does so here) As far as exporting to .opus then use external program option (ffmpeg), read here http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?p=268956&sid=c58f3fb830bbc42bc032521784b0c15c#p268956

Comment: @doug I have taken the substantial liberty of expanding on your succinct comment to produce a full answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Doug has pointed out Audacity has the ability to easily *import* Opus files under Ubuntu 17.04 and also the ability to *export* as Opus with a small work around. To illustrate:

**1. Importing Opus Files with Audacity**

Audacity easily imports Opus files either by:

1. Drag and drop the Opus files directly onto the main Audacity window
2. File --> Import --> Audio from the Audacity main window

This has tested without flaw on my installation of Audacity 2.1.2 under Ubuntu 17.04.

**2. Exporting Opus Files with Audacity**

Audacity can export as Opus but does not have the capability to directly export as Opus or to use the conventional 'Custom FFmpeg Export' setting.

Instead go to:

```
File --> Export --> External Program
```

and change the Command options to something like the following:

[image]

And to make copying and pasting a little easier here is the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i - -c:a libopus -b:a 128k "%f"
```

And this should give you the results you are after...

**Notes:**

- [Audacity: Exporting to an External Program](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/exporting_to_an_external_program.html) sends audio via a command-line to an external application, either for processing or for encoding as a file.

Comment: I tried the command in the export audio/external program window, but the file doesn't appear. I get an output from `libopus`, I'll post the output.

Comment: @SarahSzabo Your copy of FFmpeg does not have support for encoding with libopus, is this the repository version for 17.04? I will double check when I get home away from this Windows computer...

Comment: This was the output of `ffmpeg -version`: `ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.3.0 (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 20170406` I just got it from git.

Comment: @SarahSzabo OIC. Bear in mind that Zesty already has a decent and reasonably fully featured version of FFmpeg in the standard repositories, you might be better off using this? However if you have compiled your own copy  recompile adding `--enable-libopus `  to your ./configure string and make sure you have the opus '-devel' packages installed: `sudo apt-get install  libopus-dev` ...

Comment: I installed the opus-devel packages, and then recompiled with the flags specified. I edited the post to clarify.

Comment: @SarahSzabo This is because you have not actually compiled from git, you have used a release version and thus quality encoding is not available. Try `ffmpeg -i -  -c:a libopus -b:a 128k "%f"` for your 'external command' and then all should be well :)

Answer (score 2):

There is need for `ffmpeg` to export opus.
First, install `opus-tools` with:

```
sudo apt install opus-tools
```

Then, one can simply use something like:

```
opusenc --bitrate 192 - "%f".ogg
```

instead of the `ffmpeg` command.

This works fine with Audacity 2.1.3 and [opusenc](https://opus-codec.org/downloads/) 0.1.9.

**EDIT**

`ffmpeg` does not support quality settings for opus. Here is part of the output using today's 3.4 git snapshot of `ffmpeg` when trying something like

```
ffmpeg -i - -c:a libopus -q:a 7  "%f"
```

as command:

```
[libopus @ 0x3f065c0] No bit rate set. Defaulting to 96000 bps.
[libopus @ 0x3f065c0] Quality-based encoding not supported, please specify a bitrate and VBR setting.
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple method I use on pc is (this is my method, it hasn't been copied from elsewhere, and I'm on Windows 10 not Ubuntu, but this may help someone):

- Open Audacity
- Open your file browser and navigate to the audio file in the Whatsapp Audio folder (whether the file is on your pc, tablet or phone)
- Click the red record button in Audacity
- Play the audio file
- When recording stops, click the square Stop button (important)
- File / Export / Export as WAV / Save to your computer

If this doesn't work for you, you need to search online re how to set up Audacity to record through your speakers or headset.

Comment: But this is Ask Ubuntu, not Ask Windows